# Previously working Python script using Google Reporting API v4 now returning 403

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I wrote a python script to pull yesterday's data from Google Analytics. I'm using OAuth v2 with Google Reporting API v4. The backbone of the script is essentially the same as Google's sample version, except I included recursion to overcome the pagination limitation and am outputting the results to a CSV file.
Today it started to return a `403` error:

```
HttpError 403 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "The caller does not have permission"
```

I did my due diligence by searching for a solution, but I already am using the `ViewID` and the computer that it's running on isn't signed into any other accounts (it exists to only run reports). I've also tried creating a new `client_secrets.json` file and verifying that I am within quotas, but the issue still persists. Nothing changed between yesterday and today, yet it refuses to run today.

**EDIT**
I'm using the same connection object, it's only instantiated once, the code is the exact same as on Google's website here -> [Hello Analytics Reporting API v4 - Python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py)

```
def initialize_analyticsreporting():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
      formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter,
      parents=[tools.argparser])
  flags = parser.parse_args([])

  flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH, scope=SCOPES,
      message=tools.message_if_missing(CLIENT_SECRETS_PATH))

  storage = file.Storage('analyticsreporting.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())

  analytics = build('analytics', 'v4', http=http, discoveryServiceUrl=DISCOVERY_URI)
  return analytics
```

I'm invoking it the batchGet method on each request like so...

```
response = analytics.reports().batchGet(body=loaded_request.get("request", {})).execute()
```

Comment: Does the user you are logged in as still have 'Read & Analyze' permissions for the View that you are extracting data from?

Comment: Yes, the account does. It was working fine days before, it also never happens on the first request, just subsequent ones, even when those requests have the same `View ID`

Comment: If it works on the first request and not on subsequent ones, it sounds like you're not passing the right credentials on subsequent calls. Would be helpful to see your code.

Comment: I've added some code. The connection object doesn't change, it's only instantiated once, and it's reused multiple times. I've tried using a try/except with exponential back-off and it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've managed to work around this by using the exponential back-off in conjunction with recursion and try/except block, similar to the method recommended by Google here -> [Error Responses](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors#backoff)

Like so:

```
try:
    response = analytics.reports().batchGet(body=loaded_request.get("request", {})).execute()
except HttpError as err:
    print(err)
    time.sleep(2**expontential_backoff)
    expontential_backoff += 1
    if expontential_backoff < 5:
        get_response(analytics, request, page_token, file_name, expontential_backoff)
    else:
        print("expontential_backoff:", expontential_backoff, "Exceeded")
    return
```

If the error hits then when by when n > 1 it usually works just fine. I'm not terribly fond of this method, ideally I would like it to work correctly.

If there is no other solution, then hopefully this will help someone in the future.